# webRTC on RaspberryPi 3 (raspbian / chromium) - VGA resolution only

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, chromium, raspbian

I am currently working on having a web page that allows the user to see a live stream of his / her webcam and then take a snapshot (so nothing special).

Everything is fine, but on a RaspberryPi 3 running raspbian with chromium browser latest (for that distro), I can't go above a resolution of 640 x 480 using the constraints.

If I go any higher than these values, the image will simply not show on the page.

some code snippet:

```
    var constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        //width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        //height: { min: 768, ideal: 960, max: 1440 }
        width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 480, ideal: 960, max: 1440 }
    }
};

[...]

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
      constraints,
      function(stream) {
        if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
          video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        } else {
          var vendorURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          video.src = vendorURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
        video.play();
      },
      function(err) {
        console.log("An error occured! " + err);
      }
    );
```

Does anyone have an Ide what I might want to look into ?
I've searched the web for the past 2 weeks but didn't find anything helpful so far...

All Ideas are highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Check the video camera that you are using and the drivers for it on the RaspberryPi.

Many webcams don't really offer video at higher than VGA (even if still images can be taken at higher resolutions).

There's also the issue of how that data gets from the webcam to the RaspberryPi. Older connections (lower than USB3 requires some minimal compression and decompression to take place between the camera and the device, and I am not sure the drivers you have support it for the rPi).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your Reply!

When I check the webcam with cheese, I get a cristall clear image with much higher resolutions (HD and FULLHD not a aproblem). The camera is a Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910)

Comment: I am not sure... I'd suggest you post this issue also in discuss-webrtc (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!aboutgroup/discuss-webrtc)

Comment: oh, that's actually a good Idea!
I should have thought about this already....

Posted the same question there, let's see if I can get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that has been working flawlessly on the Rpi for years, even on the Pi Zero now is [UV4L](https://linux-projects.org), 30fps Full Hd + Audio + datachannel *all optionally bidirectional*, Hardware-encoded, p2p or with Janus up to 3-4 people. @Tsahi Levent-Levi you might be surprised, as I know you are actively promoting WebRTC: [example](https://www.linux-projects.org/2016/12/31/immersive-telepresence/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is a bit tricky in this case, but using this constraints should allow a higher resolution than 640*480:

```
  constraints = {
      "mandatory": {
          "maxWidth": 1280,
          "maxHeight": 720
      },
      "optional": [{
              "minWidth": 1024
          },
          {
              "minHeight": 768
          }
      ]
  };
```